# WAMP page not displaying over internet

Tags: apache, wamp, httpd.conf

I am running my WAMP server on my laptop running Windows 8.

I have a site set up at /www/MySite and made some Changes to my httpd.conf file as to make it accessable on the web, I've opened port 8080 in my router, and I've changed the ports to 8080 in my config.

Here's what I can do: I can get the site to work on these addresses:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/ok4pgm/
http://localhost:8080/ok4pgm/
http://192.168.1.77:8080/ok4pgm/

the first addresses can't be used for obvious reasons, and I'm guessing the second can't be used either since the address to my router begins with 192.168 and I therefore suspect it's some kind of local thing.

My IP address seems to be 213.114.161.6 (WhatsMyIP.org, canyouseeme.org & no-ip client) but it won't work on http://213.114.161.6:8080/ok4pgm/ - not even if I momentarily disable my firewall (and no, canyouseeme can't see port 80 nor 8080)

my httpd.conf:

```
ServerSignature On
ServerTokens Full

ServerRoot "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9"

Define APACHE24 Apache2.4

Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080

LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php5apache2_4.dll"

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>


ServerAdmin admin@example.com

ServerName localhost:8080

HostnameLookups Off

DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"

<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride all


Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

<IfModule logio_module>
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
</IfModule>

CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
TypesConfig conf/mime.types

AddEncoding x-compress .Z
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3

</IfModule>

EnableSendfile off

AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none

Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"
```

please, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your router is a computer. When someone makes a request to your Internet facing IP address, they are making it to your router and not to your workstation.

As well as opening the port on your router, you also need to configure *port forwarding* so that the router will pass on the request to your workstation.